# Best file path for importing navigation with jquery - VSC

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, navigation, filepath, nav

I'm building my first custom website, and I'm using jquery to add my navigation, or header, to every page. What I need help figuring out, is how to get the images to display on every page. Right now if I change the file path I can make the images show in the assets/header.html file and on the homepage level, but any folder deeper wont display the images. What file path do I need for the images to show on every page, or do I just have to wait until the website is live and use the full path just in the header.html file?

This loads the navigation and images:

```
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#header").load("assets/header.html");
      $("#footer").load("assets/footer.html");
    });
  </script>
```

This loads the navigation but no images:

```
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#header").load("../assets/header.html");
                    $("#footer").load("../assets/footer.html");
                });
            </script>
```

Example of file paths of images which had to be changed in different places to work. I can also change these to ../ and ../images, but once again it will load on some pages and not others.

```
    <img src="../page-lucky\images\NYC_entertainer_Page_Lucky_mobile_cell_phone_icon_image.png"/>
    <img src="../page-lucky\images\Singer_for_hire_Page_Lucky_website_email_social_media_logo.png"/>
```

I'm new, so easy to understand wording is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Easiest way to address the image issue is to not use relative paths on the image src.  Fully qualify the url so regardless of what nesting you are on, they always go to the same place

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to stay away from using the rest of the URL since it includes all of my VSC folders too, but I'm not seeing a way around it. At least I only have to change the URLS in one place. :)